# Show that the distinguished logarithm of a probability measure is subadditive

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, exponential-function

If $\varphi_\mu$ is the characteristic function of a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$, we can easily show that $$\left|\varphi_\mu(y_1+y_2)-\varphi_\mu(y_1)\varphi_\mu(y_2)\right|^2\le\left(1-\left|\varphi_\mu(y_1)\right|^2\right)\left(1-\left|\varphi_\mu(y_2)\right|^2\right)\tag1$$ for all $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb R^d$.

Now assume $0\not\in\varphi_\mu(\mathbb R^d)$. We can then show that there is a unique continuous $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb C$ with $f(0)=0$ and $$\varphi_\mu=e^f\tag2.$$ Let $\mu_t$ be the probability measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ with characteristic funciton $$\varphi_{\mu_t}=e^{tf}$$ for $t\ge0$.

> How can we show that $$\left|f(y_1+y_2)-f(y_1)-f(y_2)\right|^2\le4\Re f(y_1)\Re f(y_2)\tag3$$ for all $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb R^d$?

The claim can be found in Theorem 6.2 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301841350_An_Introduction_to_L%27evy_and_Feller_Processes_Advanced_Courses_in_Mathematics_-_CRM_Barcelona_2014).

The proof claims that $(3)$ would follow from applying $(1)$ for $\mu$ replaced by $\mu_t$, dividing by $t>0$ and letting $t\to0+$, but I don't get how this yields $(3)$.

It's clear to me that $$\left|\varphi_{\mu_t}\right|=e^{t\Re f}\tag4$$ though ...

Answer (score 0):

Write down the series expansion of the exponentials, divide by $t^{2}$ and then let $t \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Applying $(1)$ yields $\left|e^{tf(y_1+y_2)}-e^{tf(y_1)}e^{tf(y_2)}\right|^2=\left(1-e^{2t\Re f(y_1)}\right)\left(1-e^{2t\Re f(y_2)}\right)$. The left-hand side tends to $f(y_1+y_2)-f(y_1)-f(y_2)$ and the right-hand side tends to $4\Re f(y_1)\Re f(y_2)$ as $t\to0+$. Shouldn't this even yield equality in $(3)$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: (I've intended to write that the left-hand side tends to $\left|f(y_1+y_2)-f(y_1)-f(y_2)\right|^2$)

Comment: If you just take the limit you get $|1-1|^{2}\leq (1-1) (1-1)$. How does that prove anything?

Comment: I mean taking the limit after dividing by $t^2$, as you've suggested.